# "Расширить" базовый класс до производного (?)

Tags: java, наследование

Есть класс-сущность для десерилиализации json. 
Пусть он будет таким:

```
public class _BaseJsonModel {
    public int field1;
    public String field2;
}
```

Теперь у нас есть класс-модель для работы непосредственно в коде:

```
public class BaseModel {
    private int field1;
    private String field2;

    public int getField1() { return field1; }
    public String getField2() { return field2; }
}
```

> Почему я не объявил сразу один класс правильно и не использовал его же
>   для считывания? - Мне не совсем нравится возвращаемая Json-структура,
>   так будет проще адаптироваться, если в API что-то сильно измениться,
>   ну и, собственно, все изменения данных должны идти через запросы на
>   сервер, а эти модели лишь для удобного чтения, а значит и сеттеров
>   быть не должно.

Загвостка в том, что есть расширенная версия этой же модели, т.е. всё те же поля с теми же данными плюс ещё пару. Чтобы не дублировать код, я создаю производные от базовых классов модели, добавляя дополнительные поля. 
Примерно вот так:

```
public class _JsonModel extend _BaseJsonModel {
    public String field3;
}
```

И соответственно:

```
public class Model extend BaseModel {
    private String field3;

    public String getField3() { return field3; }
}
```

Далее я думал просто написать конструкторы, которые бы принимали в качестве аргумента json-модель и инициализировали соответствующие поля. И всё вроде бы отлично даже учитывая ограничение Java на то, что вызов конструктора базового (супер) класса должен быть в самом начале.

Загвоздка в том, что эти json-модели есть поля в более сложной структуре и там они могут быть null. Соответственно, мне хотелось бы, чтобы в таком случае и мои классы-модели были null, что не работает с конструктором, ибо даже если я конструктору в качестве аргумента отдам null, компилятор выделит переменной память и ссылаться она будет уже не на null.

Тогда я подумал, что можно было бы создать статический метод, который бы принимал json-модель и отдавал бы null, если json-модель ссылается на null и готовый объект в обратном случае.

С базовым классом всё оказалось отлично:

```
public static BaseModel convertFromJsonModel(_BaseJsonModel _baseJsonModel){
    if (_baseModel == null) { return null; }

    BaseModel baseModel = new BaseModel();
    baseModel.field1 = _baseJsonModel.field1;
    baseModel.field2 = _baseJsonModel.field2;

    return baseModel;
}
```

Проблемы начались, когда мне потребовалось создать аналогичный метод в производном классе. Если я попытаюсь сделать аналогично, то столкнусь с проблемой того, что я не смогу инициализировать два поля из базового класса, ибо не имею к ним доступа и сеттеров у них нет.

```
public static Model convertFromJsonModel(_JsonModel _jsonModel){
    if (_jsonModel == null) { return null; }

    Model model = new Model();
    //super.field1 = _jsonModel.field1; (?)
    //super.field2 = _jsonModel.field2; (?)
    model.field3 = _jsonModel.field3;

    return model;
}
```

**UPD:** 
Неужели единственный выход это объявление полей базового класса как *protected*?
Будет ли это вообще корректно с точки зрения архитектуры? 
Особенно учитывая, что такие поля будут доступны ещё и внутри пакета =/

Comment: А в чём сложность всегда использовать самый расширенный вариант жсона, и в случае чего просто полей добавить к десериализованному объекту?

Comment: @PeterSamokhin в том, что сервер не отдаёт всегда расширенные версии. Например, сущность при запросе по id возвращает полную структуру, а при запросе списка возвращает сокращённую структуру, как итог, чтобы получить список развернутых структур, нужно отправлять дополнительные запросы, причём по каждой сущности. Такие запросы отнимают время, да и сервер не пропустит их в таком количестве.

Comment: Так если в определенном ответе не будет нужных полей, то в десериализованном объекте просто эти поля будут `null`, разве нет? Добавьте проверок, я думаю это решит проблему.

Comment: @PeterSamokhin вы не поняли. Там где сервер отдаёт сокращённую структуру, я буду оперировать ей. Допустим результат из поисковой строки мне вернёт частичную структуру, которой достаточно, чтобы отобразить результаты поиска в виде превью-списка, а когда пользователь выберет конкретную сущность, то получать развернутую сущность уже по конкретному id. Пользуюсь я обеими сущностями, как сокращённой, так и расширенной.

Answer (score 0):

Слишком сложно у вас написано. Надеюсь смысл понял. 
Для расширенной версии какого-либо холдера лично использую такой вариант:

Материнский класс холдер:

```
public class MotherHolder
{
    private int _field1;
    private int _field2;

    public MotherHolder(int field1, int field2)
    {
        _field1 = field1;
        _field2 = field2;
    }

    public int getField1()
    {
        return _field1;
    }

    public int getField2()
    {
        return _field2;
    }
}
```

Дочерний, расширенный:

```
public class ChildrenHolder extends MotherHolder
{
    private final int _field3;
    private final int _field4;

    public ChildrenHolder(int field1, int field2, int field3, int field4)
    {
        super(field1, field2);

        _field3 = field3;
        _field4 = field4;
    }

    public final int getField3()
    {
        return _field3;
    }

    public final int getField4()
    {
        return _field4;
    }
}
```

Если нужно инициализировать любое из полей в материнском классе, просто добавьте метод присваивания:

```
public void setField(int field)
{
  _filed = field;
}
```

- **public** - доступ без ограничений;
- **private** - только в текущем классе;
- **protected** - в текущем, производных (дочерних) и в пределах общего пакета.

Тут уж выбирайте сами область видимости переменной чтобы не было коллизий.